# Display text based on date and time

Tags: wordpress, time

I have a countdown to display "embeded video" but I would like to add title above "You will see the video when the countdown is completed"

How can I add title to this so the title will dissapear when countdown is completed? Or maybe you have a new code to display title based on date and time?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 20, 2021 09:42:10").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  '<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/631000875?h=612f03d2b3&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Innovate Healthcare Event"></iframe></div>'
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the solution works then you have to tick and upvote the answer.

Comment: Hey you neither accepted the answer nor upvoted it. Please do that at the earliest. 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the title when the timer is up then try this

```
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById('title').style.display="none"; // add this line.
    document.getElementByIdd("demo").innerHTML =
  '<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/631000875?h=612f03d2b3&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Innovate Healthcare Event"></iframe></div>'
  }
```